# Makefile With an IF Statement

Tags: unix, if-statement, makefile

I have a `Makefile` which creates build a programme called monitor:

```
fo/monitor: fo/monitor.c fo/inotify.c
    (cd fo ; $(MAKE) monitor)
```

I have two types of system that I can run my Make on, and only wish to have have one installer.

So I would like to add an `IF` statement to this to check for a file, and if it exists, then to build the `monitor`.

```
fo/monitor:
    if [ -f path/to/file/exists ]; \
    then \
        fo/monitor.c fo/inotify.c \
            (cd fo ; $(MAKE) monitor) \
    else \
        echo "" >/dev/null \
    fi \
```

The problem is, when I attempt to run the Makefile - it falls over becuase it does not like this code - can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fo/monitor.c` and `fo/inotify.c` have to be added to the targets dependencies, and not in the `if` statement. You can also use the `-C` option of `make` instead of using a subshell. And you do have to echo *nothing* in *nothing*.

This should be good:

```
fo/monitor: fo/monitor.c fo/inotify.c
    if [ -f path/to/file/exists ]; then \
        $(MAKE) -C fo monitor; \
    fi
```

Comment: Okay, it is not complaining about the `IF` anymore, now it is saying `*** missing separator.  Stop.`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @DustinCook Be sure that you have replace the 4 spaces by tabs!

Comment: Yes, I just realised that one!!  Woops!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This recipe promises to produce `fo/monitor` but it may not, so that every time you run make it will keep trying to build `fo/monitor` because it is not a phony target.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin You are totally wright. This is why I recommend to use your response.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to depend on that target only if `path/to/file/exists` exists:

```
# add fo/monitor dependency only if path/to/file/exists exists
all : $(shell test -e path/to/file/exists && echo "fo/monitor")

fo/monitor: fo/monitor.c fo/inotify.c
    ${MAKE} -C ${@D}
```

Comment: This is more cleaner than an if statement. +1

Comment: @jml I am a bit averse to if statements in recipes, I must admit, they hurt my sense of style.